# save jquery ui-sortable positions to DB

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

Im trying to replicate the functionality of this page (http://www.kissfm.ro/fresh-top-40/) for a friend who has a small web radio. The site is setup in wordpress fyi.

So my question is, after searching stackoverflow, how do i save/get the revised charts based on the users input? i found how to save single submittions but how do i get the final charts based on the user choice?

Thanks in advance!
(code or link to tutorial welcome!)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

make your HTML sortable, add javascript, and save to php on update.

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li id="1">elem 1</li>
    <li id="2">elem 2</li>
    <li id="3">elem 3</li>
    <li id="4">elem 4</li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
            $.get('saveSortable.php', {order:newOrder});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks! that did the trick, although it took us another day to figure out how to save every submission and get the median values.

Comment: should you be using a post instead of a get since you are modifying data on the server?  Also, what happens if server save isn't successful; maybe should use beforeStop method and issue a cancel on the sort if server save fails?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but what I do is just add a hidden input element in every LI. They would all have a the same name with [] at the end. This way, when you post the form containing the UL, you will get an array in your post values in the order you just put your list.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Sortable docs we have to prefix the LI's id with some string.
Then if we serialize the sortable in the update method we'll get a nice array in php e.g. new_order[]=1&new_order[]=2 etc.

```
var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

<ul id="sortable">
    <li id="new_order_1">elem 1</li>
    <li id="new_order_2">elem 2</li>
    <li id="new_order_3">elem 3</li>
    <li id="new_order_4">elem 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You may POST with input  to DB and save it
Here we go:
<ul id="sortable">
    <li id="1"><input type ="text" value="elem 1"/></li>
    <li id="2"><input type="text" value="elem 2"/></li>
   .
   .
</ul>
<style>
 #sortable{
  border: hidden;
}
</style>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
            $.get('saveSortable.php', {order:newOrder});
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it  helps ;)