# How do I stop List Items from jumping when using inline-block with JQuery draggable?

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, css

Just discovered the joys of JQuery's "draggable" API, but I want to display my list using inline-block. This makes the list items jump when you drag them, does anyone know how to fix this?

The code I'm using is:

```
   $(function() {
        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VVaqu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VVaqu/6/)*

Just add : `float:left;` to your `li` elements

```
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
 float:left;
 /*other styles...*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great. I'm going to try and extend this project so I can save the new positions using this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097168/save-jquery-ui-sortable-positions-to-db. Do you think that will work / any tips?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan, may I ask you to take a look at a jQuery  draggable and droppable related question (bounty-added) here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498364/jquery-drag-and-drop-simulation-does-not-work-for-the-last-draggable ?

Answer (score 6):

Another solution if you can't use float:

```
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The vertical-align:top is important.